# Почему происходит замечание(E_NOTICE)?можно ли избежать этого?

Tags: php

1) Форма.

---

```
<form action='#' method='POST'>
<label for='login'>Введите логин.</label><br/>
<input type='text' name='login' maxlength='15' id='login' /><?php echo "<span id='err_login'>{$errors['login']}</span>"; ?>
</form>
```

2) Контроллер.

---

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
$errors = array();
if(empty($_POST['login'])){
$errors['login'] = 'Вы не заполнили логин.';
}
elseif (mb_strlen($_POST['login'])<3){
$errors['login'] = 'Логин слишком короткий.';
}
```

Ошибка:

---

**Notice: Undefined variable: errors in**

Вопросы:
1) почему происходит замечание(E_NOTICE)?
2) можно ли избежать этого?
3) Может стоит убрать E_NOTICE через error_reporting?

Answer (score 2):

Происходит потому что $errors не инициализирована. в начале скрипта инициализируй эту переменную $errors = array();
на счет отключения -- я бы не отключал, лучше учиться писать код правильно.

Comment: Ты оказался не прав. $error уже инициализирован на контроллере.
Короче надо было лишь проверить на существование. То есть существует ли isset(error[login]){echo...}

Comment: ага, теперь вижу, но если бы ошибка была полностью написана, то было бы понятнее))  

коммент на счет отключения все равно в силе ;)

Comment: Да,спасибо)..С твоей помощью пришел к решению задачи)..

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='text' name='login' maxlength='15' id='login' /><?php 
if(isset($errors['login'])){
 echo "<span id='err_login'>".$errors['login']."</span>"; }?>
```